# Multiple overloads of __compressed_pair error implementing unordered_set

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, set, unordered-set

I'm trying to implement an unordered_set in my bfs algorithm, but it gives me this errors:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:2412:40:
>   error: multiple overloads
>         of '__compressed_pair' instantiate to the same signature 'void (_T2_param)' (aka 'void (int)')
>       _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY explicit __compressed_pair(_T2_param __t2)
>                                          ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__hash_table:969:59:
>   note: in instantiation
>         of template class 'std::__1::__compressed_pair >' requested here
>       __compressed_pair                  __p2_;
>                                                             ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/unordered_set:353:13:
>   note: in
>         instantiation of template class 'std::__1::__hash_table, std::__1::equal_to, std::__1::allocator
>
> > '
> >           requested here
> >         __table __table_;
> >                 ^ AICharques.cc:47:21: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::unordered_set,
> >     std::__1::equal_to,
> >           std::__1::allocator >' requested here
> >             unordered_set visited;
> >                                ^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:2410:40:
> >     note: previous declaration
> >           is here
> >         _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY explicit __compressed_pair(_T1_param __t1)

And this is my code:

```
void radar_bfs(Pos actualPos){
    queue<Pos> frontier;
    frontier.push(actualPos);
    unordered_set<Pos> visited;
    visited.insert(actualPos);

    while(!frontier.empty()){
        auto current = frontier.front();
        frontier.pop();

        for(auto next : neighbors(current)) {
            if(not visited.count(next)){
                frontier.push(next);
                visited.insert(next);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pos is a struct that contains two ints, i and j.(position in a board).
When i use just a set instead, the errors disappear.

Comment: Can you give us a [mcve] that gives this error?

Comment: @NathanOliver sorry, i was still editing.